# Bower install from Network Service account

Tags: node.js, bower

Trying to get my TFS agent to run bower install but it doesn't look like it's working to run bower from a Network Servcice account?

```
C:\>npm -g list
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- bower@1.8.0

C:\>npm install -g bower
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower -> C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- bower@1.8.0

C:\>bower
'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Also tried adding C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\bower\bin to the global PATH

Comment: After you added bower to PATH, did you restart the command prompt ?

Comment: Yes. Also tried adding C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower and restarting cmd. No difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with help from the [npm github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15464)

Added the path from npm prefix -g to the global path and installed bower with -g again.

```
C:\>npm prefix -g
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm
```